# Cómo seleccionar elementos con document.querySelectorAll

Tags: javascript, html, css

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
<div> 
  <p></p>
  <p><a href="#"><img src="" /></a></p>
  <p><a href="#"><img src="" /></a></p>
  <p><a href="#"><img src="" /></a></p>
  <p></p>
  <p></p>
</div>
```

Cuando pruebo en la consola de comandos esto:

```
document.querySelectorAll('div p:not(a)')
// o lo siguiente
document.querySelectorAll('p:not(a)')
```

Me aparecen los 6 elementos `p`, sin embargo yo quiero que solo me aparezcan los 3 elementos `p` que no tienen elementos `a` como hijos.

PD: en css hago esto `div p:not(a) {}` y si le puedo dar estilos solo a los elementos `p` que no tienen elementos `a` como hijo.
¿Cómo podría obtener solo los elementos `p` que no tienen hijos a con `document.querySelectorAll`?

Comment: Eso no es posible, ni con CSS como decís. No se puede obtener información de los nodos para hacer eso.

Comment: Con CSS yo pude darle estilos a los elementos p que no tenían hijos a

Comment: Por ejemplo, yo coloco esto en la consola de comandos: document.querySelectorAll('p>a') y solo me muestra: NodeList(3) y me salen los 3 elementos p que tienen hijos a, eso está bien... Pero yo quiero digamos lo contrario, que me muestre solo los 3 elementos p que no tienen hijos a

Comment: Si pero eso no funciona con CSS, [ejemplo](https://jsfiddle.net/aptLrbx8/).

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll('p>a') ` a mi me da error en la consola. Mi pregunta es, ¿tienes acceso a modificar los elementos `p` o no?

Comment: ¿Usas alguna biblioteca JavaScript (p.e. jQuery)?

Answer (score 2):

Voy a proponer dos soluciones, sin tener que pasar por procesos algo *oscuros*  para lograr lo que quieres.

### Solución 1

Si tienes acceso a modificar directamente los elementos del DOM, puedes agrupar los `p` que tienen enlaces mediante una clase (o cualquier otro elemento de tu preferencia) y luego seleccionas aquellos que no tengan esa clase.

Supongamos que marcas los `p` con enlaces con `class="with-link"`:

```js
var notLink = document.querySelectorAll('div p:not(.with-link)')
console.log(notLink);
```

```html
<div>
  <p></p>
  <p class="with-link">
    <a href="#"><img src="" /></a>
  </p>
  <p class="with-link">
    <a href="#"><img src="" /></a>
  </p>
  <p class="with-link">
    <a href="#"><img src="" /></a>
  </p>
  <p></p>
</div>
```

---

### Solución 2

Puedes recoger en un array los elementos donde `firstElementChild`<sup>1</sup> sea `null`, o sea, aquellos elementos que no tengan `a`. A partir de ese array puedes hacer lo que necesites con los elementos que no tienen enlace.

```js
var allP = document.querySelectorAll('div p');
var notLink = new Array();

allP.forEach(function(element) {
    if(!element.firstElementChild){
        notLink.push(element);
   }
});

console.log(notLink);
```

```html
<div>
  <p><a href="#"><img src="" />Click aquí</a></p>
  <p><a href="#"><img src="" />Click aquí</a></p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...</p>
  <p><a href="#"><img src="" />Click aquí</a></p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...</p>
</div>
```

---

#### Notas:

<sup>1</sup> <sub>Si hay problemas de compatibilidad, dado que `firstElementChild`  funciona a partir de IE 9 (por ejemplo), se puede sustituir el condicional por `if (element.children.length == 0){ ... };`</sub>

Answer (score 1):

No estoy seguro de que se pueda hacer lo que pides directamente mediante [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelectorAll). Haciéndolo en dos pasos podrías usar un código como este:

```
// Seleccionamos todos los elementos 'p' en un NodeList
var p = document.querySelectorAll('p');

// Dado que NodeList no tiene método filter lo invocamos a través de Array
r = Array.prototype.filter.call(p, x => 
    // Nos quedamos con todos los Nodos que no tengan hijos
    (!x.firstChild) || 
    // y con aquellos nodos que teniendo un
    // hijo directo ese hijo directo no es un 'a'
    (x.firstChild && x.firstChild.tagName !== 'A')
);
console.log(r)
```

Answer (score 1):

Otra alternativa [ES6](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/) usando [sintaxis extendida](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Operadores/Sintaxis_Spread#Compatibilidad_del_navegador) para crear un [`array`] y luego con un [`filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/filter#Browser_compatibility) retornar los elementos que no contienen hijos `a` mediante una [función flecha](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Funciones/Arrow_functions#Compatibilidad_en_navegadores)

```js
let PnotA = [...document.querySelectorAll('div p')]
     .filter(x => x.querySelectorAll('a').length === 0);

for (i = 0; i < PnotA.length; i++) {
  PnotA[i].style.backgroundColor = "red";
}


console.log(PnotA);
```

```css
p {margin: 0; padding:0;}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>1</p>
  <p><a href="#"><img src="" />2</a></p>
  <p><a href="#"><img src="" />3</a></p>
  <p><a href="#"><img src="" />4</a></p>
  <p>5</p>
  <p><span><a href="#"><img src="" />6</a></span></p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

viendo tu codigo e investigando un poco no es posible hacer eso con `queryselectall` la única manera posible es de esta manera(que puede encontrar y hacer fue de esta manera):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>
  <div>
    <p id="1"></p>
  <p id="2"><a href="#"><img src="" />link</a></p>
  <p id="3"><a href="#"><img src="" />link</a></p>
  <p id="4"><a href="#"><img src="" />link</a></p>
  <p id="5"></p>
  <p id="6"></p>
  </div>
<script>
 var p01 = document.getElementById('1');
 var p02 = document.getElementById('2');
 var p03 = document.getElementById('3');
 var p04 = document.getElementById('4');
 var p05 = document.getElementById('5');
 var p06 = document.getElementById('6');
  
   if(p01.firstChild){
   console.log(" tiene");
   }else{
     console.log("no tiene"); 
   }
   if(p02.firstChild){
   console.log(" tiene");
   }else{
     console.log("no tiene"); 
   }
   if(p03.firstChild){
   console.log(" tiene");
   }else{
     console.log("no tiene"); 
   }
   if(p04.firstChild){
   console.log(" tiene");
   }else{
     console.log("no tiene"); 
   }
   if(p05.firstChild){
   console.log(" tiene");
   }else{
     console.log("no tiene"); 
   }
   if(p06.firstChild){
   console.log(" tiene");
   }else{
     console.log("no tiene"); 
   }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

explico el codigo:

primero le creo a cada elemento p un id para que sea identificado ,después con con un if veo si cada p(osea cada id del 1-6) cuenta con algún hijo y si tiene un hijo me muestra en consola que tiene hijo y si no tiene me muestra que no tiene.

post:investigue en stackoverflow en inglés sobre esto y me base en código de otro para hacerlo,quizá este código no sea lo que buscas porque necesitas hacerlo con  `document.querySelectorAll` pero igualmente investigue por internet y no hay respuesta y la mas cercana es el que cree yo.

espero que te sirva y si alguien mas gusta mejorar el codigo con justo pueden comentar en la respuesta de como podria mejorarlo(se que no es el codigo mas limpio pero es el mas cercano a su necesidad)