# ¿Cómo saber los elementos que tienen anchor tag <a> usando Javascript puro?

Tags: javascript

En este contenido HTML:

```
<div>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...</p>
  <p><a href="#">Click aquí</a></p>
  <p><a href="#">Click aquí</a></p>
  <p><a href="#">Click aquí</a></p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...</p>
</div>
```

No encuentro la manera de determinar cuáles `p` tienen una etiqueta `<a> ... </a>` **usando Javascript puro**.

He recurrido a leer lo que hay en `data` de `childNodes[0]` :

```
var allP = document.querySelectorAll('div p')
var notLink = new Array();

allP.forEach(function(element) {
  if (element.childNodes[0].data) {
    notLink.push(element);
  }
});

console.log(notLink);
```

Pero es una solución muy precaria. Fallaría si hubiera siquiera un espacio en los `p` que tienen enlace.

Lo que quisiera es una forma segura de saber directamente los `p` que tienen anchor tag, ¿es posible con Javascript puro?

Comment: @JackNavaRow yo intenté `element.getElementsByTagName("a")` y me da error. Ojo, yo sólo quiero los `p` dentro de ese `div` que tengan `<a>...</a>` dentro.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

De esta manera obtendrías las etiquetas "p" que contengan una etiqueta "a" con su respectivo atributo "href":

```
var allP = document.querySelectorAll('div p a[href]');
var notLink = new Array();

allP.forEach(function(element) {
    notLink.push(element.parentElement);
});

console.log(notLink);
```

Comment: Funciona, aunque no llego a entender cómo funciona lo de `parentElement`... Tampoco entiendo por qué no es posible usar algo parecido a `querySelectorAll('div p not:(a[href])')` para seleccionar los `p` que no tienen anchor tag. La duda me vino a raíz de [esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/178688/29967).

Comment: selecciona todos los `a` que tienen como padre un `p` y como abuelo un `div` luego los recorre y devuelve el padre de cada `a` (los `p`)

Comment: @A.Cedano tienes la respuesta de por que no selecciona div p not:(a[href]) ?

Answer (score 1):

Alternativa usando `map` y sintaxis extendida para convertir el nodelist a un array

```js
// P que contenga A, devolver el P
let PconA = [...document.querySelectorAll('div p a')]
     .map(x => x.closest('p'));

// P que contenga A, devolver el nodo padre (puede ser un span dentro del P)
let PconA2 = [...document.querySelectorAll('div p a')]
     .map(x => x.parentNode);

// P que contengan A sólo en el primer nivel (nietos A abstenerse) devuelve el P
let PconA3 = [...document.querySelectorAll('div p > a')]
     .map(x => x.parentNode);


for (i = 0; i < PconA.length; i++) {
  PconA[i].style.backgroundColor = "red";
}

for (i = 0; i < PconA2.length; i++) {
  PconA2[i].style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
}

for (i = 0; i < PconA3.length; i++) {
  PconA3[i].style.backgroundColor = "green";
}


console.log(PconA, PconA2, PconA3);
```

```css
p {margin: 0; padding:0;}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>asdfasdf 1</p>
  <p><a href="#">asdfasdf asdf 2</a></p>
  <p>asd asdf dsaf <a href="#">asdfadsf 3</a></p>
  <p><a href="#">asdf asdf 4</a></p>
  <p>asd asdf 5</p>
  <p>asd asd asf<span><a href="#">asdf asdf 6</a> asdasf</span></p>
</div>
```

variación de https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/178769/81450

Comment: Interesante respuesta Alo, pero observo que el último elemento no lo recupera como `p`, recupera solamente el `span` ¿?

Comment: jaja si, es por el filtro no tan estricto, tendría que buscar hacia arriba el ancestro que sea `p` ó limitarlo a sólo `a` hijo directo

Comment: Bueno sí, aunque se trata de buscar en sí los `p` que tienen la etiqueta `a` dentro. Si se adapta para que busque en los hijos sería perfecto.

Comment: ahi experimento con varias variantes, todos los p que tengan algún A.
los P que tengan algún A pero pintar al padre (el span por ejemplo) y pintar los P que tengan un A en el primer nivel